# Is it possible to make OpenGL draw GL_LINES with a pen-like stroke?

Tags: opengl

What I mean by a "pen-like" stroke is this: when you draw on a paper with a circular bud pen. You will get a line with a round beginning and ending. In case, my explanation isn't good enough, please see "Join Round" and "Cap Round" at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html

In Java, we can set the stroke and such to have such line, so is it possible to have OpenGL to do it natively?

Comment: For an authoritative statement that OpenGL doesn't do this: [14.100 How do I turn on wide-line endpoint capping or mitering?](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/rasterization.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in OpenGL itself. However, there's [AmanithVG GLE](http://www.amanith.org/project.html), a library built on top of OpenGL, that can do it.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL doesn't have high level drawing functions like that.